# В данном примере цикл многократно (n) раз печатает каждую дату текущего месяца. Но получаю ошибку: "ValueError: day is out of range for month"

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime, calendar

Есть цикл, который выводит определенное количество строк с датами. /
В данном примере многократно (**`12`**) раз печатается каждая дата текущего месяца.

И он даже выводит данные, но так же выводит и ошибку:

> "ValueError: day is out of range for month"

Подскажите как исправить?

```
import datetime

len_special = 12
# цикл для проставления даты
len_total = (len_special*31)
days = 0
for total in range(len_total):
    days += 1
    for iterat in range(len_special):
        datess = datetime.datetime.now().replace(day=days)
        now = datess.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        print(now)
```

Comment: пора бы уже знать, что, например, 32 дня нет ни в одном месяце.

Comment: советую добавить в код разных print() в разных местах, чтобы знать, чему какая переменная равна.

Comment: @Эникейщик этот цикл должен многократно напечатать каждое число месяца, в данном примере каждый день декабря печатается по 12 раз. Такая логика.

Comment: наводящий вопрос: на каком числе заканчивается этот цикл?

Comment: @Эникейщик подскажите как тогда быть, если нужно определенное количество раз (len_special) напечатать каждое число текущего месяца?

Comment: Зачем вам строчка len_total = (len_special*31)? У вас два цикла - один - число месяца, другой - количество раз.

Comment: @Эникейщик print() на каждой строке - лишнее, для этого есть визуализаторы и функция debug в IDE.

Comment: @vlados155 ну, например, в IDLE нет ни визуализатора, не функции debug. Про каждую строчку я и не говорил, к тому же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто напечатать каждую дату текущего месяца по 12 раз можно так:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

len_special = 12
today = datetime.now()
y,m = today.year,today.month
for d in range(1, monthrange(y,m)[1]+1):
    print('\n'.join([f'{d:02d}.{m:02d}.{y:04d}'] * len_special))
```

Comment: спасибо, но я получаю ошибку "print('\n'.join([f'{d:02d}.{m:02d}.{y:04d}'] * len_special))
**NameError: name 'm' is not defined**" я понимаю, что 'm' и 'y' это месяц и год, но как объяснить это Питону я не знаю...
Пробывал M и Y, не помогает.

Comment: @Александр ваша правда. Исправил, сейчас вроде все ОК. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, я не понимаю вашей логики, но предложу попробовать следующее:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

len_special = 12
#??? цикл для проставления даты
len_total = (len_special * 31)                      # ??? 31

to_day = datetime.now()                             # текущая дата и время

for delta, total in enumerate(range(len_total)):
    datess = to_day + timedelta(delta)
    now = datess.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    print(f'{now}\n' * len_special)
```

---

**Update**

> Можно попросить Вас изменить цикл, нужны все даты текущего месяца с 01 по последнюю, и убрать пробелы между датами. Я попытался он меня их стал в строчку печатать...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

len_special = 12
#??? цикл для проставления даты
len_total = (len_special * 31)                      # ??? 31

#to_day = datetime.now()                            # текущая дата и время
to_day = datetime.now().replace(day=1)                          # +++

for delta, total in enumerate(range(len_total)):
    datess = to_day + timedelta(delta)
    now = datess.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
#    print(f'{now}\n' * len_special)
    print(* [f'{now}' for _ in range(len_special)], sep='\n')   # +++
```

Comment: @s-nick спасибо, близко. Можно попросить Вас изменить цикл, нужны все даты текущего месяца с 01 по последнюю, и убрать пробелы между датами.
Я попытался, но получил печать дат в строках...

Comment: Вот здесь "len_total = (len_special * 31)" я попытался заложить логику: len_special -повторений по количеству дней в месяце

Comment: @Александр количество повторений у вас уже заложено во внутреннем цикле.

Comment: @Александр я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

len_special = 55

print(*[datetime.now() + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(1, len_special + 1)], sep='\n')
#2021-12-17 10:52:25.888090
# ...
#2022-02-09 10:52:25.888168

print(*[date.today() + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(1, len_special + 1)], sep='\n')
#2021-12-17
# ...
#2022-02-09
```